# What is a bitmap in C?

Tags: c, bitmap

A bitmap is an [array of bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array).  How is it implemented in C?

Answer (score 53):

I assume you're asking how to *implement* a bit map (or bit array) in C. Surprisingly, the [Bit_array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array) entry on wikipedia describes the concept, but doesn't actually show how to to implement the fundamental operations, so here goes.

In short, make an array of your favorite unsigned type, and do the right arithmetic to decide how to set/clear a bit in it.

```
#include <limits.h>    /* for CHAR_BIT */
#include <stdint.h>   /* for uint32_t */

typedef uint32_t word_t;
enum { BITS_PER_WORD = sizeof(word_t) * CHAR_BIT };
#define WORD_OFFSET(b) ((b) / BITS_PER_WORD)
#define BIT_OFFSET(b)  ((b) % BITS_PER_WORD)

void set_bit(word_t *words, int n) { 
    words[WORD_OFFSET(n)] |= (1 << BIT_OFFSET(n));
}

void clear_bit(word_t *words, int n) {
    words[WORD_OFFSET(n)] &= ~(1 << BIT_OFFSET(n)); 
}

int get_bit(word_t *words, int n) {
    word_t bit = words[WORD_OFFSET(n)] & (1 << BIT_OFFSET(n));
    return bit != 0; 
}
```

Comment: A literal `1` is a regular, signed `int`, which raises two problems: it isn't guaranteed to be 32 bits, and `1 << 31` is undefined behavior (because of the sign bit). All literal `1`s in the above code should be replaced with the unsigned 32-bit `(word_t) 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "bit field".

```sh
$ cat src/bitmap.c
#include <stdio.h>

#define BITS 4
struct BITMAP {
        unsigned value : 1;
} bit[BITS];

int main(){

        bit[0].value = 0;
        bit[1].value = 1;
        // implicit truncation from 'int' to bit-field changes value from 2 to 0 [-Wbit/field-constant-conversion]
        bit[2].value = 2;
        bit[3].value = 3;

        int i;
        for ( i=0; i < BITS ; i++){
                printf("Value of bit %i is %u\n", i, bit[i].value);
        }
}
```

result

```sh
$ gcc src/bitmap.c -lm -o bitmap && ./bitmap
src/bitmap.c: In function ‘main’:
src/bitmap.c:14:24: warning: unsigned conversion from ‘int’ to ‘unsigned char:1’ changes value from ‘2’ to ‘0’ [-Woverflow]
   14 |         bit[2].value = 2;
      |                        ^
src/bitmap.c:15:24: warning: unsigned conversion from ‘int’ to ‘unsigned char:1’ changes value from ‘3’ to ‘1’ [-Woverflow]
   15 |         bit[3].value = 3;
      |                        ^
Value of bit 0 is 0
Value of bit 1 is 1
Value of bit 2 is 0
Value of bit 3 is 1
```

Comment: The actual size of `struct BITMAP` will be larger than 1 bit as it has to be aligned -- if `sizeof(unsigned)` is 4 bytes, then `sizeof(struct BITMAP)` is 4 bytes too.