# Implementing bitmap in C

Tags: c, bitmap

I am following this [What is a bitmap in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225998/what-is-a-bitmap-in-c) question to implement Bitmap in C.

I have shared my code below.

Problem I am facing is, the implementation is setting the bit correctly on the given position, but few other bits are also turning on. I have shared an example case where it is breaking. I am not able to debug it since last two days.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// assuming a char is made up of 8 bits
enum { BITS_PER_WORD = sizeof(unsigned long) * 8 };
/*
utility functions for bit position calculations
*/
unsigned long word_offset(unsigned long pos){
    return pos/BITS_PER_WORD;
}

size_t bit_offset(unsigned long pos){
    return pos%BITS_PER_WORD;
}


typedef struct bitmapNode{
    void *mem;
    unsigned long len;
}bitmapNode;


/*
utility funtion used to set bit
*/
bool setbitUtility(void* mem, unsigned long pos){
    unsigned long *ptr = mem;
    ptr += word_offset(pos);
    *ptr |= (1 << bit_offset(pos));
    return true;
}

/*
utility funtion used to clear bit (make bit = 0)
*/
bool clearbitUtility(void* mem, unsigned long pos){
    unsigned long *ptr = mem;
    ptr += word_offset(pos);
    *ptr &= ~(1 << bit_offset(pos));
    return true;
}

/*
utility funtion used to get bit at pos
*/
bool getbitUtility(void* mem, unsigned long pos){
    unsigned long *ptr = mem;
    ptr += word_offset(pos);
    return 0 != (*ptr & (1 << bit_offset(pos)));
}

/*
Returns an empty bitmap node
*/
bitmapNode* newBitmapNode(){
    bitmapNode* node = NULL;
    node = malloc(sizeof(bitmapNode));
    if(node){
        node->len = 0;
    }
    return node;
}

/*
Initialize a bitmap node. Expands the memory to hold bit at given position
*/
bitmapNode* initBitmapNode(long long pos, bool bit){
    unsigned long len = word_offset(pos);
    bitmapNode* node = NULL;
    node = newBitmapNode();
    if(node){
        node->mem = malloc(sizeof(unsigned long) * (len + 1));
        if(node->mem){
            memset(node->mem, 0, sizeof(node->mem));
            node->len = len + 1;
            bit ? setbitUtility(node->mem, pos) : clearbitUtility(node->mem, pos);
            return node;
        } else {
            free(node);
        }
    }
    return node;
}

bool getBit(bitmapNode* node, unsigned long pos){
    if(pos < node->len * BITS_PER_WORD){
        return getbitUtility(node->mem, pos);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/*
sets the bit stored in node at given position to value passed in bit(0 or 1)
*/
bool setBit(bitmapNode* node, unsigned long pos, bool bit){
    unsigned long len = word_offset(pos);
    void *new_start;
    bool ret;
    if(pos < node->len * BITS_PER_WORD){
        pos = (unsigned long)pos;
        ret = getbitUtility(node->mem, pos);
        bit ? setbitUtility(node->mem, pos) : clearbitUtility(node->mem, pos);
    } else {
        pos = (unsigned long)pos;
        node->mem = realloc(node->mem, sizeof(unsigned long) * (len + 1));
        if(node->mem){
            new_start = node->mem + node->len;
            memset(new_start, 0, len + 1 - node->len);
            node->len = len + 1;
            ret = false;
            bit ? setbitUtility(node->mem, pos) : clearbitUtility(node->mem, pos);
        } else {
            // have to return err
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

int main(){
    bitmapNode *bitmap = initBitmapNode(0, 0);
    char cmd[100];
    int n, bit;
    unsigned long pos;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    bool ret = false;
    while(n--){
        printf("Enter command: ");
        scanf("%s", cmd);
        if(strcmp(cmd, "getbit") == 0){
            printf("%s\n", "Enter position: ");
            scanf("%lu",  &pos);
            ret = getBit(bitmap, pos);
            if(ret)
                printf("%s\n", "1");
            else
                printf("%s\n", "0" );
        } else if(strcmp(cmd, "setbit") == 0){
            printf("%s\n", "Enter position and bit (space separated): ");
            scanf("%lu %d", &pos, &bit);
            setBit(bitmap, pos, bit);
            printf("%s\n", "OK" );
        }
    }
    free(bitmap->mem);
    free(bitmap);
    return 0;
}
```

> ./a.out

5

Enter command: setbit

Enter position and bit (space separated):

271 1

OK

Enter command: getbit

Enter position:

271

1

Enter command: getbit

Enter position:

223

1 << This should be 0

Comment: This has nothing to do with your problem, but be consistent. Use `void *x` or `void* x` and do it consistently, and of course prefer `void *x` for many reasons.

Comment: @Rup: terrible advice. If `calloc()` is useful it's certainly NOT for hiding bugs. And that's precisely why it should be used very carefully.

Comment: What is this doing `bit ? setbitUtility(node->mem, pos) : clearbitUtility(node->mem, pos);`?

Comment: @iharob Hiding bugs? He's failing to zero the initial malloc: that is a bug. (Although I see now he is zeroing the realloc, so maybe that's not his problem here.)

Comment: @iharob line that u mentioned simply checks if bit is false it clears the bit at pos, if the bit is true, it sets the bit at pos

Comment: @Arun Have you tried stepping through this in a debugger? If that's not possible for whatever reason, write some code to dump the contents of `mem`, e.g. as hex, and use that to examine the state at the point it's going wrong. It's fun for us to try and spot errors from the code, but you should know how to track this down yourself.

Comment: `sizeof` yields the number of bytes of an object. But a byte is not required to have 8 bits. See `CHAR_BIT`! And as you use `size_t` already: why not use it for `pos` and other variables, too?

Comment: @Rup forcing to zero bytes is wrong. If you intend to use them for any purpose except if you really want them to be zero. If zeroing was necessary all the time, then allocation functions would do that for you.

Comment: @iharob Well we're initializing an empty bitmap here so yes we really do want them to be zero.

Comment: @Rup you are right, I appologize.

Comment: @Olaf : Bitmap I am trying to implement shall hold maximum 4294967295 bits. I am using unsigned long to avoid any overflow.

Comment: @ArunKaushik: 1) Unsigned integers cannot overflow! They wrap. 2) How can integer division overflow? 3) Read what `size_t` means. If it cannot hold the index, `unsigned long` will also not be able to. Worse, `size_t` **might be** even larger, e.g. on IL32P64 systems like Windows (what is `sizeof(size_t)` on that system?).

Comment: @Olaf : thank you for that piece of advice, I will explore size_t and use it appropriately.

Comment: @ArunKaushik: Worse is you assumption of 8 bits/byte. But if you rely on **that**, you should use fixed-width types and forget about that enum-constant. (btw. that is an `int` and might cause additional trouble).

Comment: In `initBitmapNode`, the line `memset(node->mem, 0, sizeof(node->mem));`  does not do what you think. `sizeof(node->mem)` evaluates to the size of the pointer (probably 4 or 8), not the size of the allocated memory block. Use `memset(node->mem, 0, sizeof(unsigned long) * (len + 1));` instead.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck : thank you very much, I have finally found and fixed all bugs in the code.

Thank you Olaf for your inputs too. 
Actually it has been a sloppy piece of coding from my end. I appreciate all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look through all your size computations. You are mixing sizes expressed in bytes and sizeof(long). You are also using pointer arithmetic on a `void` type (`mem`).

As a consequence, your `memset` calls don't clear the entire memory block, just a small part of it.

The most important fix would be in `setBit`:

```
    unsigned long *new_start;


    node->mem = realloc(node->mem, sizeof(unsigned long) * (len + 1));
    if(node->mem){
        new_start = (unsigned long *)(node->mem) + node->len;  // Added cast 
        memset(new_start, 0, sizeof(long) * (len + 1 - node->len));  // Multply by sizeof long to get size in bytes
        ...
```