# How to implement bitmap array in C using uint64_t data type?

Tags: c, bitmap, 64-bit

I am trying to implement bitmap array in C.
I've read and copy-paste from this link: [What is a bitmap in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225998/what-is-a-bitmap-in-c)

```
#include <limits.h>    /* for CHAR_BIT */
#include <stdint.h>   /* for uint32_t */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef uint32_t word_t; // I want to change this, from uint32_t to uint64_t
enum { BITS_PER_WORD = sizeof(word_t) * CHAR_BIT };
#define WORD_OFFSET(b) ((b) / BITS_PER_WORD)
#define BIT_OFFSET(b)  ((b) % BITS_PER_WORD)

void set_bit(word_t *words, int n) { 
  words[WORD_OFFSET(n)] |= (1 << BIT_OFFSET(n));
}

void clear_bit(word_t *words, int n) {
  words[WORD_OFFSET(n)] &= ~(1 << BIT_OFFSET(n)); 
}

int get_bit(word_t *words, int n) {
  word_t bit = words[WORD_OFFSET(n)] & (1 << BIT_OFFSET(n));
  return bit != 0; 
}

int main(){
  printf("sizeof(word_t)=%i\n",sizeof(word_t));
  printf("CHAR_BIT=%i\n",CHAR_BIT);
  printf("BITS_PER_WORD=%i\n",BITS_PER_WORD);
  word_t x;

  set_bit(&x, 0);
  printf("x=%u\n",x);
  set_bit(&x, 1);
  printf("x=%u\n",x);
  set_bit(&x, 2);
  printf("x=%u\n",x);

  return 0;
}
```

Using uint32_t, the code works well. It prints x value: 1, 3, and 7, respectively like this:

```
[izzatul@mycomputer latihan]$ ./a.out
sizeof(word_t)=8
CHAR_BIT=8
BITS_PER_WORD=64
x=1
x=3
```

x=7

It doesn't work. The x value become 1295807169 etc, which was not I expected. I expect it to be the same as before (1, 3, 7). Can someone help me fix that code?

I know "<<" is bit shifting, which mean you shift the bit to the left (or adding 0 to the right).
But I am still not sure how to modify the code myself.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show us the actual output of your program, as well as the expected output. Also, when dealing with bits it's often more useful to print numbers as hexadecimal instead (easier to see exactly which bits are set or not).

Comment: It's a shot into blue but `1` is an `int` constant. A cast could help e.g.: `(word_t)1`. Otherwise, parts of your computation might be done in `int` and parts with `uint64_t` and this might have side-effects.

Comment: I suggest that you print bit values in hex, that should give you a much better idea of what is going on. use %x with your printf calls (also

Comment: I'm pretty sure Scheff is right. int n is not merely used as index but is part of the integer math so your result might get truncated or offset in a wrong way.

Comment: Understanding of bit operators is necessary to understand fully what happens in your code. This link may help: [Bitwise Operators in C and C++: A Tutorial](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html). (Better would be, to buy and read a book.) ;-)

Comment: Also, printf will not expect a 64 bit type unless you tell it with the ll size modifier, so printf("x=%llx\n", x); without that you will only get the high or low 32 bit (depending on system endianness) part of the value.

Comment: Wait, I'm still editing my question.

Comment: Note that you did not set `x` to a known value (like `0`) before you started setting bits.  You get indeterminate results when you start with indeterminate values.

Comment: Please try to avoid having to edit questions.  Consider deleting a question while you make edits to it, then undeleting it.

Comment: It might also be worth printing results in hexadecimal rather than, or as well as, in decimal.  It is easier to see what numbers like 1295807169 (base 10) are as bit patterns if you print in hex.

Comment: I've modified it based on all your advices here. It works well now (in uint64_t), I think. I am using cast (word_t)1 and printing it using hexadecimal. It helps me understand it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the code uses `1` integer constants. All such integer constants have a type just like variables and it is per default `int`, which is likely the same as `int32_t` on your system.

Left shifting a signed integer like `int32_t` more than 30 bits invokes undefined behavior, because you'll be shifting data into the sign bit. As a rule of thumb, never use signed variables together with bitwise operators.

The correct fix in this case is to replace every instance of `1 << BIT_OFFSET(n)` with:

```
(word_t)1 << BIT_OFFSET(n)
```

Alternatively use `1ull` suffix, but that may produce needlessly slow code on smaller systems.

---

Please note that the correct format specifier for printf is `printf("x=%"PRIu64 "\n",x);` from inttypes.h.